# Doing multiple jobs at the same time in C++

Tags: c++, windows

I have made a login Command Line interface in C++ where a marquee will run for indefinite time and in the next line a user can enter his id and password. I want both these work i.e. marquee and id input at the same time but with the below code only marquee is running for infinite time. I am using windows OS and i am new to C++ so I am not able to apply thread concepts.

```
char m[]={"- A cool marquee effect. Programmed by Roneet -"};
int main()
{
    marquee();
    cout<<setw(35)<<"Enter Username : ";
    getline(cin,str);
    cout<<setw(35)<<"Enter Password : ";

    return 0;
}
void marquee()
{
    while(a<131)
    {
        p=m[0];
        m[0]=m[c];
        m[c]=p;
        for(j=1;j<=b;j++)
            cout<<m[j];
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){}
        c--;
        cout<<"\r";
        if(c<1){c=b;a++;if(a==100)N=51500;}
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: What's that `for(j=0;j<N;j++){}` loop for? It probably does nothing (depending on what `N` is, it could also be undefined).

Comment: That's an awful lot of magic numbers, you know? 131, 100, 51500... And the variable names are not exactly self-explaining, either. `a`, `p`, `m`, `c`, `j`, `N`, `b`... Who should ever be able to maintain this thing? You won't understand it yourself in two weeks from now (I know that I wouldn't if I wrote it).

Comment: Don't use `system("PAUSE")`, you can use in example `#include <limits> std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');` instead.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, std streams are not thread safe, you need to add `std::mutex` to protect each `std::cout` operation.

Secondly, to easily execute a function in a separate thread, use `std::async`

```
#include <future>

std::future<void> fut = std::async(&marquee);
```

Example:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <future>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::atomic<bool> cond{ false };

void marquee()
{
    while (!cond)
    {
        std::cout << '*' << std::flush;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cerr.tie(nullptr);

    std::cout << "Enter username and then password: " << std::flush;

    std::future<void> task = std::async(std::launch::async, &marquee);

    std::string user, pass;
    std::cin >> user >> pass;

    cond = true;

    task.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i am using minGW .Its not working .It is not able to detect future.h

Comment: because this is C++11

Comment: Anyway of executing it in MinGW ?

Comment: AFAIR, with MinGW, `async` uses `deferred` policy instead of `async` policy so, you have to explicitly use the correct policy.